# Chart.js showing nothing on canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a graphic in my .html file in the altervista ftp.
Here's my code:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js" />
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                ...
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                ...
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Why I'm getting nothing in canvas?
Also the console does not show errors.

Comment: You sure you don't have a syntax error in the complete code? It works in the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yg3pfm4q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my error editing the first script from this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js" />
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js" ></script>
```

as suggested by @j.ian.le

And adding

```
responsive: false,
```

under `options: {`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `...` under `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` or add colors according to the number of labels.

Comment: Yes, I added `...` just to have a shorter code but in my complete code there aren't

Comment: Try adding a closing `</script>` at the end of the first script

Answer (score 0):

You need to call myChart.update() after initializing the chart.

Comment: It seems does not make any changes